# Trying to read an eeprom buffer, but i get this error - 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'

Tags: c, avr

Can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong?

```
 int main (void)
 {

 char str[16];
 unsigned char *s;
 unsigned char i, byte;
//  extern char (*p)[];
char string1[16] = "9999999999";
char (*p)[16] = &string1;
//  uint16_t i;
sysclk_init();
board_init();
ioport_init();

    LCD_pin_init();

  PORTC.DIRSET = PIN0_bm;
 // ioport_set_pin_dir(LED,IOPORT_DIR_OUTPUT);

/* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */

PORTB.OUT = eeprom_read_byte(&a[3]);
NVM_CTRLB |= NVM_EEMAPEN_bm;
PORTB.OUT = *(&a[3] + 0x1000);


nvm_eeprom_erase_and_write_buffer(0x00,*p,2);
while(1)
{


 > str[byte] = nvm_eeprom_read_buffer(0x00,*p,2);
    byte++;

    //s[0]=str;
    //s[16]='\0';

    lcd_cmd(0x01);
    lcd_select_location(0x01,0x00);
    lcd_puts(str);

    if(str == 0x41)
    {
   PORTC.OUTTGL = PIN0_bm;
   delay_s(1);
 //   ioport_set_pin_level(LED,0);
    lcd_cmd(0x01);
    lcd_select_location(0x01,0x00);
    lcd_puts(s); 
    //   delay_s(3);
    }
  }
}
```

i get the error : 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'
what should be done? I am trying to read eeprom data from xmega controller. i could successfully write and read a byte but to read and write more than one byte i am getting errors.

this the earlier working code which returns a byte.

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <nvm.h>
#include "LCD1/LCD_public.h"
#include <string.h>


  void lcd_ready();
  void lcd_data_out();
  void lcd_puts();

   unsigned char a[10];


 uint8_t eeprom_read_byte(uint8_t address)
 {
  nvm_wait_until_ready();

  NVM.ADDR0 = address & 0xFF;
  NVM.ADDR1 = (address >> 8) & 0x1F;
  NVM.ADDR2 = 0x00;

    NVM.CMD = NVM_CMD_READ_EEPROM_gc;
    nvm_exec();

    return NVM.DATA0;
    }

     int main (void)
 {
        /* Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()). */
   char str[16];
    unsigned char *s;
   unsigned char i, byte;
    //  extern char (*p)[];
      char string1[16] = "9999999999";
     char (*p)[16] = &string1;
    //  uint16_t i;
      sysclk_init();
      board_init();
       ioport_init();

      LCD_pin_init();

     PORTC.DIRSET = PIN0_bm;
  //    ioport_set_pin_dir(LED,IOPORT_DIR_OUTPUT);


      PORTB.OUT = eeprom_read_byte(&a[3]);
       NVM_CTRLB |= NVM_EEMAPEN_bm;
     PORTB.OUT = *(&a[3] + 0x1000);


    nvm_eeprom_erase_and_write_buffer(0x00);
    while(1)
    {
    str = nvm_eeprom_read_buffer(0x00,0x41);
    //byte++;

    s[0]=str;
    s[16]='\0';


    if(str == 0x41)
    {
   PORTC.OUTTGL = PIN0_bm;
   delay_s(1);
//   ioport_set_pin_level(LED,0);
    lcd_cmd(0x01);
    lcd_select_location(0x01,0x00);
    lcd_puts(s); 
    //   delay_s(3);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: We don't have the definitions of your `nvram_eeprom` functions so can't say for sure but it seems that `nvram_eeprom_read_buffer` does not return a value yet you are calling it as if it does. If you need further help please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Where is `a` defined?

Comment: @kaylum yes it seems so that the function is not returning but I used the same `nvm_eeprom_read_buffer` function to read a byte. It returns the read byte and stores it in NVM data register. I will see for a verifiable example, although if i had one, i myself would have taken it as a reference.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have defined a as a global variable, outside main loop.

Comment: @Manasi.C " I used the same nvm_eeprom_read_buffer function to read a byte". Please show that code. And an MCVE is not a "working" example of the code. It is exactly the opposite. It is complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: @kaylum okay, i am sorry i was not aware. Sharing with you the initial code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to believe `nvm_eeprom_read_buffer` would *return* a byte read from the EEPROM and you could assign that to `str[byte]`. It doesn't and you cannot. That function is `void` and puts the read bytes into the buffer you submit (`p` in your example code).

There are more hickups in your code, but these should go into a separate question each.